# android app deployment and publishing

Tags: android

I am about to finish my first android app.
Could you give me some knowledge/links/references about stuff like
deployment, app signing, android market, app publishing etc

Thanks

Comment: As of now, this is not a real question. What would you like to know about deployment, app signing, the android market, or app publishing? There could be volumes written on each one of those topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is in the dev guide:

http://d.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

http://d.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html

http://d.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

http://d.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html

http://d.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Answer (score 0):

[android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html) contains everything you need to know.

And this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4MssvYA48g) is also a good source to get some knowledge on app publishing.